# Issue with Message Ordering in JPA Entity List After Update Operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity which has a list of messages which should be always ordered by creation date.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChatEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chatEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("creationDate")
    private List<MessageEntity> messageEntityList;
}
```

But the test fails when I do an update for one of the messages, showing the latest updated message as the one down the list, whereas it should be showing the first created message instead as that would be the oldest one. The application is working fine (the application also fails if I remove the order by annotation from the message entity list, and this is what I want to assert for).

```
@Test
void testMessagesAreOrderedByCreationDateAfterUpdate() {
    // Given the user sends a message to another user
    Message message1 = Message.builder().content("firstMessage").userToId(user2.getId()).build();
    rq.body(message1).post("/api/v1/ht/messages");

    // And the user sends another message to the same user
    Message message2 = Message.builder().content("secondMessage").userToId(user2.getId()).build();
    rq.body(message2).post("/api/v1/ht/messages");

    // When the user retrieves the messages
    Response getMessageResponse = rq.get("/api/v1/ht/messages");

    // Then the messages should be ordered by creation date
    List<Message> messages = Arrays.asList(getMessageResponse.as(Message[].class));
    assertTrue(messages.get(0).getCreationDate().isBefore(messages.get(1).getCreationDate()));

    // When the user updates the first message -> This makes the tests fail
    message1.setContent("firstMessageUpdated");
    rq.body(message1).put("/api/v1/ht/messages/" + messages.get(0).getId());

    // Then the messages should be ordered by creation date
    Response updatedMessageResponse = rq.get("/api/v1/ht/messages");
    List<Message> updatedMessages = Arrays.asList(updatedMessageResponse.as(Message[].class));
    assertTrue(updatedMessages.get(0).getCreationDate().isBefore(updatedMessages.get(1).getCreationDate()));
}
```

This is the service implementation:

```
@Override
public Message updateMessage(UUID messageId, Message message) {
    UserEntity userFromEntity = userService.getCurrentUser();

    MessageEntity messageEntity = messageRepository.findById(messageId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new MessageNotFoundException(MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION));

    if (!userFromEntity.getId().equals(messageEntity.getUserFromEntity().getId())) {
        throw new EntityDoesNotBelongToUserException(ENTITY_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_USER_EXCEPTION);
    }

    messageEntity.setContent(message.getContent());
    messageEntity = messageRepository.save(messageEntity);

    return messageMapper.toModel(messageEntity);
}
```

[image]

Thank you very much.